# SOAPUI groovy Capture Response with a condition

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a script made in groovy, and I want to save a specific link from the response, and I dont know how to script it.

I want to save the link that is in documentMetadata > directURL but with the condition that the filename starts with ImageWhite__* (also need here some expresion as can the numbers after ImageWhite__ will change from request to request)

My script to capture is :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def myTestCase = context.testCase //myTestCase contains the test case
propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties") // get the Property TestStep object

//Get the value of the fields from the properties step, we will use this as a file name
field1 = propTestStep.getPropertyValue("Field1").toString()
field2 = propTestStep.getPropertyValue("Field2").toString()

// Write Response to XMl File
def myXmlResponse = "D:\\Response\\"+field2+".txt"

def response = context.expand('${Request#Response#//*:documentMetadata//*:directURL}') //Replace Request with your Request Name
def res = new File(myXmlResponse)
res.write(response, "UTF-8")
```

My response xml is this :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <S:Body>
      <searchFileResponse xmlns:ns3="-" xmlns:ns2="-" xmlns="-">
         <Header>
            <ns2:ChannelID></ns2:ChannelID>
            <ns2:CallingSystemID></ns2:CallingSystemID>
            <ns2:UserID></ns2:UserID>
            <ns2:ResponseReference>unused</ns2:ResponseReference>
            <ns2:DateTimeRequest>2017-01-03T13:42:42.441+02:00</ns2:DateTimeRequest>
            <ns2:DateTimeReceived>2022-03-31T09:43:17.881+03:00</ns2:DateTimeReceived>
            <ns2:DateTimeReply>2022-03-31T09:43:18.091+03:00</ns2:DateTimeReply>
            <ns2:RequestLanguage>ro</ns2:RequestLanguage>
         </Header>
         <ServiceExecutionStatus>Ok</ServiceExecutionStatus>
         <Errors xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
         <Warnings xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
         <returnCode>0</returnCode>
         <errorDetails xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
         <documentMetadata>
            <documentId>196692125</documentId>
            <documentRef>190821S662234027</documentRef>
            <documentType xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <documentMimeType xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <library>IDSCAN</library>
            <libraryPath>2019/08/21</libraryPath>
            <fileName>ImageIR__4782325272340084988.jpg</fileName>
            <directURL>http://something</directURL>
            <author xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <authoringGroup xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <title xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <subject xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <description>ABCDFA</description>
            <properties>
               <name>audit.last_updated_date</name>
               <value>1566367303197</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>audit.creation_date</name>
               <value>1566334800000</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>CIC</name>
               <value>23321</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>file.size</name>
               <value>33915</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>file.lastmodified</name>
               <value>1566367244000</value>
            </properties>
         </documentMetadata>
         <documentMetadata>
            <documentId>196692127</documentId>
            <documentRef>190821S662234027</documentRef>
            <documentType xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <documentMimeType xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <library>IDSCAN</library>
            <libraryPath>2019/08/21</libraryPath>
            <fileName>ImageUV__8003143531657716008.jpg</fileName>
            <directURL>http://something</directURL>
            <author xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <authoringGroup xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <title xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <subject xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <description>ABCDFA</description>
            <properties>
               <name>audit.last_updated_date</name>
               <value>1566367303194</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>audit.creation_date</name>
               <value>1566334800000</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>CIC</name>
               <value>23321</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>file.size</name>
               <value>45383</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>file.lastmodified</name>
               <value>1566367244000</value>
            </properties>
         </documentMetadata>
         <documentMetadata>
            <documentId>196692123</documentId>
            <documentRef>190821S662234027</documentRef>
            <documentType xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <documentMimeType xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <library>IDSCAN</library>
            <libraryPath>2019/08/21</libraryPath>
            <fileName>ImageWhite__5219450603368724974.jpg</fileName>
            <directURL>http://something...</directURL>
            <author xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <authoringGroup xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <title xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <subject xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <description>ABCDFA</description>
            <properties>
               <name>audit.last_updated_date</name>
               <value>1566367303176</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>audit.creation_date</name>
               <value>1566334800000</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>CIC</name>
               <value>23321</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>file.size</name>
               <value>56122</value>
            </properties>
            <properties>
               <name>file.lastmodified</name>
               <value>1566367244000</value>
            </properties>
         </documentMetadata>
      </searchFileResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [XmlSlurper](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html):

```
def S_Envelope = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parse(responseXML)

S_Envelope."S:Body".searchFileResponse.documentMetadata.'**'.find { documentMetadata ->
    if (documentMetadata.fileName.text().startsWith('ImageWhite__'))
        println documentMetadata.directURL
}
```

If your response XML is in a file, parse it with `.parse(FileName)`, and if it is in a string use `.parseText(response)`

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question with the full capture script, please help me because I am noob about this, I tried to update my script with what you provided me, but with no succes. My response is a string, I only save the needed response to a file.

Comment: Do you use a property transfer step to get the values into `Field1` and `Field2` properties ? Where do you read the response XML ?

Comment: Yes, in Properties Step I have Field1 and  Field2 that coresponds to an xls file for column A and B, the response I read it here :  def response = context.expand('${Request#Response#//*:documentMetadata//*:directURL}')

Comment: If you want it conditional, i.e. filename starts with ImageWhite, I suggest you get the response in XML format with something like `def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)` and parse it with XmlSlurper, instead of a property transfer step.

Comment: I dont get the response from a property transfer step , that is used just to name the resulted file from the response.

Comment: Follow my previous comment instead of doing the line `def response = context.expand(...` and it should work.

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: I have done like this, not getting any errors but no file is written in my location also :     
    def res = new XmlHolder(context.response)
    res."S:Body".searchFileResponse.documentMetadata.'**'.find { documentMetadata ->
        if (documentMetadata.fileName.text().startsWith('ImageWhite__'))
           res.write(response, "UTF-8") 
    }